# tableau software, how to display only combined categories on a map

Tags: visualization, tableau-api

I have a map where all the customers of a company are represented.

Each customer can purchase several product categories.

So I placed a quick filter to select only customers who bought a specific product categories combination.

However, the table continues to display customers who only purchase the product C or B.
I would like to retain only the customers bought the product C and B (or other combinaison)

I highlighted on the image the customers who should be appear
[image explication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV1K9.png)

I tried this tutorial but without success...

Comment: Hey, could you provide us with a sample data set.

Answer (score 0):

I usually work with a little workaround. I hope someone else will comment on how to solve this issue properly.

What I do:

First I create a calculated Variable like for example:

```
GetIntersection

IF [Product Categories] = "Product cat B" THEN 1
ELSEIF [Product Categories] = "Product cat C" THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Then I can filter by SUM(GetIntersection).

SUM(GetIntersection) = 2 would be the filter, if you want the customers who bought both Products B and C.